# localStorage and jQuery (no work css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm doing the first two pages of received data from the form and stores it in localStorage:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
        font-size px: <input id="fontsize" type="text" name="fontsize" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var inpX = document.getElementById('fontsize');
  var x = parseFloat(inpX.value);
  localStorage.setItem('inpX', x);
```

on the second page write the code jquery increases the font:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var fontsX = localStorage.getItem('inpX');
 $("#info").css('font-size':'fontsX +'px'');
});
```

but nothing happens. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$("#info").css('font-size',fontsX +'px');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax issues, you need to pass the css property and value as 2 arguments or pass a object

```
$("#info").css('font-size', fontsX +'px');
```

Comment: ok thanks, and if the example is more difficult?$("#info").css('text-shadow','#6374AB'+shadowX+'px'+shadowY+'px'+shadowRad+'px');seems to have written correctly but does not work.

Comment: @comSaaxov `$("#info").css('text-shadow', '#6374AB ' + shadowX + 'px ' + shadowY + ' px ' + shadowRad + 'px');` - I think you missed to leave some spaces between the property values

Comment: $("#info").css('text-shadow','#6374AB'+' '+shadowX+'px'+' '+shadowY+'px'+' '+shadowRad+'px'); thanks it works

Answer (score 2):

Colon is used for *object* notation (when you pass an object of properties). So one more version to set css property:

```
$("#info").css({'font-size': fontsX + 'px'});
```

or even shorter

```
$("#info").css({fontSize: fontsX + 'px'});
```

since jQuery will normalize snake-case names to cameCase.